# AuthenticationProvider UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken returns Ljava.lang.String

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

in our grails 2.4.4 project we want to use the Spring Security Core Plugin which we declare in BuildConfig.groovy this way:

compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC4'

For authentication against a REST service we implement a custom AuthenticationProvider:

```
class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
def springSecurityService

Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication;
    String username = auth.getPrincipal()
    String password = auth.getCredentials()

    println "username:" + username
    println "password:" + password
```

The CustomAuthenticationProvider.authenticate is invoked when entering a username and password in the Login form.

Unfortunately when accessing the form values via auth.getPrincipal() or auth.getCredentials() the returned value is always a String containing a value like this **[Ljava.lang.String;@6ecd6d25**

When debugging the application it seems that the values for the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken are not filled correctly from the request.

Does anybody know whats going wrong here?

Comment: You're confusing things by making Groovy convert the value to a String. When you declare the type to be `String`, Groovy will call `toString` on the object if it's not a `String`. That's the output of `toString` for an array of Strings - `[L` means it's a 1-dimensional array of an object type (`[[L` would be 2-d, etc.) and it's appending `java.lang.String` to tell you the object type. The rest is the standard suffix of the default `toString` implementation, i.e. an @ symbol followed by the hashCode value in hex.  Add `println authentication.dump()` at the top of the method to see what's there.

Comment: You'll get an array like that when there are two or more values for the same param name, e.g. `/foo/bar?x=1&y=2&x=3`. That will have "2" for the "y" param but an array with both "1" and "3" for "x".

Comment: The output of authetication.dump is: <org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@a7f16075 principal=[Ljava.lang.String;@4dcb93db credentials=[Ljava.lang.String;@705836c3 details=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffff6a82: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 0F009DBA8133821DE6189B67BABB5830 authorities=[] authenticated=false>

Comment: When debugging the request object in UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter I notice that the username is stored in an LinkedHashMap with the key "j_username". It's value is a indeed an Sting array with one entry.

Comment: [null, null, null, null, null, null, j_password=[Ljava.lang.String;@143c4b38, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, j_username=[Ljava.lang.String;@1f3fc767, null]

Comment: It's not one entry, you're just not seeing the contents, only the `toString` of an array (again). Try `println authentication.principal` and `println authentication.credential` - Groovy will print the individual array elements like you see when you println a List

Comment: as expected the output of println is the same: username:[Ljava.lang.String;@1267efd1
password:[Ljava.lang.String;@65b18bc7   because these are the values stored in the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken

Comment: As I wrote before, I think the origin of the problem is located in UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter where these values are read from the request and stored in the UsernameAuthenticationToken.

Comment: Right, the code there just calls `request.getParameter()` which assumes that there's only one value for each parameter name. But the core issue is that you're sending two or more. Try not doing that.

Comment: We are using the default login form from the security plugin. The POST body looks good as it sends only one value for password and username: j_username=asd&j_password=asd

Comment: Thank you for you help. I found the problem was caused by a Filter class of our project that manipulated the request object.